# how can redirect after a dispatcher exception?

Tags: zend-framework, dispatcher, front-controller

On zend framework inside my bootstrap file i have the following code:

```
$frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance(); 

try 
{
    $front->dispatch();
} 
catch (Exception $e) 
{
    echo "Something wrong happen";
}
```

Instead the ugly message i want to redirect to a custom controller... how can i do that if i can not use $frontController to redirect .... ?

Thanks for your help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zend will redirect to ErrorController if it is set.

> By default, Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler will forward to ErrorController::errorAction()

See Section [12.10.5.2.](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.plugins.html)

Answer (score 1):

ZendFramework has a [helper class](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/Zend_Controller/Zend_Controller_Action_Helper/Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Redirector.html) for handling redirects.

Sample usage (from your controller):

```
$redirectHelper = $this->_helper->getHelper('Redirector');
$redirectHelper->gotoUrl('controller/action');
```

You can also call redirect directly from your controller, i.e.

```
$this->_redirect($url);
```